# Nvidia causes problem with my system

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I have a new MSI GF65 Thin and installed Ubuntu on it (Ubuntu 20.04). I haven’t done something fancy on my System yet. The System is almost untouched.

After I have partitioned my drive and stuff I have encountered a problem. Everytime I turned my computer off the following screen occured (Picture 1). Seconds after that error message the computer went off. The message was not exactly the same everytime. I wanted to figure it out later and ignored it for a bit, because everything was working fine.

Now something new occured and I think it is related to the same problem. Now the system starts to produce an error during runtime and in use. I have to manually restart my computer. Then it is working "fine" again. (Picture 2)
It is obvious that it has something to do with my Nvidia GPU and/or the driver. I have a Nvidia RTX 3060. I have no experiences with problems related to GPUs, someone has any tips for me or where to look?

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

Comment: Hello. There is no such version of Ubuntu as 20.4

Comment: Hi. Sorry, I mean 20.04.4. My bad.

Comment: Try adding the pci=realloc in your /etc/default/grub, then sudo update-grub   . GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=realloc"

Comment: Thanks! It worked. The message during shutdown is away and so far no issues during runtime.