# Can’t run drivers for RTX 3060 (laptop) (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: drivers, 20.04, nvidia, kernel, graphics

I've been using Ubuntu 20.04 alongside ROS Noetic for my course in my previous laptop which had an AMD CPU with an iGPU, so never really had to struggle with drivers. I had to get a new laptop (ASUS TUF Gaming F15 2022) which has an **Intel i7-12700H and an RTX 3060**. The 12th gen processor (as far as I know) means I had to install a newer kernel (which was a hassle by itself because the laptop wouldn't boot to GUI (or not at all in some cases, had to do a minimal install with no updates and no extra drivers/proprietary software and unplug the ethernet cable during the whole process)).

I ended up using mainline to install the **5.16.20 kernel** via the Ctrl + Alt + F2 CLI, but it still didn't boot into GUI until I sudo apt installed the **nvidia drivers 470**. Seeing that this worked I would have thought that the NVIDIA GPU was the one rendering the desktop, but when I run nvidia-smi it outputs the "not installed or not running" error.

````
```

**aaron@lap-aarongrt:~$** sudo lshw -C display
[sudo] password for aaron: 
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: NVIDIA Corporation
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: a1
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:620-61f memory:5f000000-5fffffff memory:6000000000-61ffffffff memory:6200000000-6201ffffff ioport:3000(size=128) memory:60000000-6007ffff
  *-display UNCLAIMED
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Intel Corporation
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 0c
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: iomemory:620-61f iomemory:400-3ff memory:622e000000-622effffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff memory:4010000000-4016ffffff memory:4020000000-40ffffffff

**aaron@lap-aarongrt:~$** nvidia-settings

ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded


ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system


(nvidia-settings:6371): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 18:28:45.665: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
** Message: 18:28:45.667: PRIME: No offloading required. Abort
** Message: 18:28:45.667: PRIME: is it supported? no
````

I spent the whole yesterday trying out solutions, including the prime-select nvidia one and a bunch more. I also disabled Secure Boot and Fast Boot and am running Dual Boot with Windows11.
I have the nvidia-bug-report if it's of any use to you guys, I can't really tell anything from it. If you have any clue of what's going on please let me know!

Thanks!

Aarón RT

Comment: Did you try adding pcie=rescan to the kernel boot parameters (file /etc/default/grub at the "quiet splash" words). Then sudo update-grub and reboot.

Comment: @ubfan1 I changed it to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie=rescan", updated the file, rebooted but sadly nvidia-smi shows the same error.

Comment: Sorry should have been pci=realloc   See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1401935/nvidia-causes-problem-with-my-system#comment2433286_1401935

Comment: I believe I had tried that one to no avail. I did a fresh install though, so maybe I'll give it another shot and let you know.

Comment: Also check that the firmware from the vendor is up-to-date.  And recheck every now and then, new laptops are usually a few revs out of date.

Comment: @ubfan1 I fixed it! Check my answer below. Thanks a lot for your help my guy!

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it following generix's answer on [this post](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/cant-run-drivers-for-rtx-3060-laptop-ubuntu-20-04/212573)

Go to https://liquorix.net/#install and follow the kernel install instructions for ubuntu:

Run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:damentz/liquorix && sudo apt-get update
```

then:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-liquorix-amd64 linux-headers-liquorix-amd64
```

reboot the system, if you choose "Advanced settings for Ubuntu" you'll see the newly installed kernel (5.17 liquorix something something). Select it.

After booting I could already use my GPU, but since I have a 12th gen Intel CPU generix said I had to also install [these](https://packages.ubuntu.com/de/impish-updates/linux-firmware) files.

Open a new terminal and run:

```
cd Downloads/

wget https://packages.ubuntu.com/de/impish-updates/all/linux-firmware/download
```

After it finishes downloading run:

```
sudo dpkg -i linux-firmware_1.201.5_all.deb
```

Change the name of the downloaded file if needed.

Reboot and I was done!