# nvidia-smi can’t detect external GPU on mac mini running ubuntu

Tags: drivers, nvidia, gpu

I have a 2016 or 2018 mac mini that has Linux as its only OS. I’ve also attached an external GPU (NVIDIA 3060 RTX Ti) in a thunderbolt enclosure. The NVIDIA drivers are all installed, and the system can detect the GPU. ‘nvidia-smi’, on the other hand, can’t talk to the drivers, so it can’t talk to the GPU. i have tried reinstalling the drivers, rebooting, purging the drivers, reinstalling the OS, and prayer. no luck. the computer also won’t reboot if the eGPU is plugged in. i would like to be able to do ML on this machine using the eGPU, so any help or advice would be much appreciated!!

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?  Does the GPU show up in the lspci output?  What Nvidia driver are you using and how did you get and install them?  A RTX3060TI is pretty new and needs a pretty new kernel, Ubuntu 2204 better than 20.04. Search this site for 3060 and see what others have done.

Comment: Hi! I'm using 22.04, the GPU shows up in the lspci output, I installed the drivers through `nvidia-cuda-toolkit` iirc, and I've also installed them through the Ubuntu software updater and the instructions on nvidia's website (w/ uninstalls and reboots in between obviously). I've looked through many, many posts on here but haven't had any luck so far.

Comment: Pretty sure there was a similar problem with a 3060 and a fix here was to add pci=realloc to the kernel boot params (edit /etc/default/grub and at the "quiet splash" add it.). Not sure which kernel, but maybe even a 5.17 if the standard 5.15 failed.

Comment: I tried adding it like you suggested; I have the 5.15 kernel right now; it doesn't reboot correctly if the GPU is plugged in (I get an error message of `NVRM: This PCI I/O region assigned to your NVIDIA device is invalid`), then it boots without any display, and rebooting without the GPU plugged in also doesn't seem to fix the problem unfortunately.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404626/can-t-run-drivers-for-rtx-3060-laptop-ubuntu-20-04?noredirect=1#comment2439712_1404626

Comment: I was able to add the liquorix kernel and reboot into it, but `nvidia-smi` still didn't work. I tried uninstalling & reinstalling, but I wasn't able to install the nvidia drivers because they aren't compatible with the liquorix kernel. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I use a Mac mini 2018 with a 3080 eGPU.
Plugged mine in the very left Thunderbolt port and I run the following after boot (Mac mini does not boot when eGPU is turned on, so I only turn it on after boot):

```
sudo -K
sudo -s
echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:01.1/remove
echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/rescan
modprobe nvidia
sudo nvidia-smi -pm 1
sudo nvidia-smi -rgc
sudo systemctl stop nvidia-persistenced
sudo systemctl start nvidia-persistenced
exit
ps aux | grep nvidia
sudo nvidia-smi
```

Use at your own risk. I am not sure if detaching and attaching the eGPU like that is a safe procedure.